# C# display text based on a returned result from and API

Tags: c#, api

I have a ping request to and API and if it is successful it returns and "ok" and if not it returns failure. I need help in changing the the code for the ping result to display some other text like "your ping was successful" and if there was and error to display "your ping failed" I am new to programing.

```
public partial class API_Menu_Ping : BasePage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string myCADeveloperKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CADeveloperKey"];
        string myCAPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CAPassword"];

        //Create credentials
        ca.api.APICredentials cred = new ca.api.APICredentials();
        cred.DeveloperKey = myCADeveloperKey;
        cred.Password = myCAPassword;

        //Create the Web Service and attach the credentials
        ca.api.AdminService svc = new ca.api.AdminService();
        svc.APICredentialsValue = cred;

        //call the method

        ca.api.APIResultOfString result = svc.Ping() ;

       PingResult.Text = result.ResultData ;

      }
    protected void PingCaApi_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Post the exact error returned by the debugger....I suspect "your ping failed" isn't it

Answer (score 1):

you're just wanting to manipulate the text to the user.  You just need an `if` statement:

```
if(result.ResultData == "ok") //or whatever a 'yes' result is
   PingResult.Text = "Your ping was successful";
else
   PingResult.Text = "Your ping failed";
```

or you can shorten it with the ternary operator:

```
PingResult.Text = (result.ResultData == "ok") ? "Your ping was successful" : "Your ping failed";
```

Comment: I have changed the the code to what is listed below. the other question I have if I wanted to dhow the error message from the API if there is one what other info would I need to add to the else statement? if that is where I need to add it?

Comment: if (result.ResultData == "OK")
            PingResult.Text = "ChannelAdvisor servers can be reached via the API.";
        else
            PingResult.Text = "ChannelAdvior servers ARE NOT accessible";
        //PingResult.Text = result.ResultData;

Answer (score 0):

I don't really like putting code that could crash into the `Page_Load` handler. If there is any error, you may not ever see it.

Also, with your long definitions, this is a great spot to get familiar with the `var` keyword.

Using that, I would write your routine as follows:

```
public partial class API_Menu_Ping : BasePage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void PingCaApi_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PingResult.Text = null;

        //Create credentials
        var cred = new ca.api.APICredentials();
        cred.DeveloperKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CADeveloperKey"];
        cred.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CAPassword"];

        //Create the Web Service and attach the credentials
        var svc = new ca.api.AdminService();
        svc.APICredentialsValue = cred;

        //call the method
        var result = svc.Ping();

       PingResult.Text = (result.ResultData == "ok") ? "your ping was successful" : "your ping failed";
    }
}
```